# Apple's 'Let's meet at our place' event (Fall 2017)

Tags: discussion, chat

### Join us in [Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat)

As many of us know, in September most years Apple hosts a press event during which new products are announced. For example, on 7 September 2016 we saw the iPhone 7 range, Apple Watch Series 2, and AirPods among the major announcements.

Apple has just issued invites to this year's event, notable because it's the first to be held at its new [Steve Jobs Theatre](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2017/02/apple-park-opens-to-employees-in-april/), itself a part of Apple's new Apple Park 'spaceship' campus!

**This event will be held at 10am on Tuesday 12 September 2017 (Pacific Time).**

Below is part of the invite Apple issued for the event:

[image]

To coincide with this, we're holding a live chat event right here using [Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat). Users are invited to join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) as the announcements unfold.

**Expected announcements**

- iPhone 7s and iPhone 7s Plus models
- a totally new *10th Anniversary* iPhone (commonly referred to as the iPhone 8, but my expectation is it won't be called that)
- wireless charging
- iOS 11 release date
- watchOS 4 release date
- macOS High Sierra release date

**Rumoured announcements**

- Apple Watch Series 3 with LTE support
- 4K Apple TV model
- iMac Pro release date
- HomePod release date

**Surprise announcements**

- Let's find out together! :)

**Time of Keynote address**

The Keynote address is scheduled for 10am on Tuesday 12 September 2017 (Pacific Time). This equates to:

- **Adelaide** - 2.30am, Wednesday 13 September
- **Amsterdam** - 7.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **Auckland** - 5.00am, Wednesday 13 September
- **Beijing** - 1.00am, Wednesday 13 September
- **Berlin** - 7.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **Hong Kong** - 1.00am, Wednesday 13 September
- **Jerusalem** - 8.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **London** - 6.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **Moscow** - 8.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **New Delhi** - 10.30pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **New York** - 1.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **Paris** - 7.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **Perth** - 1.00am, Wednesday 13 September
- **Rio de Janeiro** - 2.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **Rome** - 7.00pm, Tuesday 12 September
- **Singapore** - 1.00am, Wednesday 13 September
- **Sydney** - 3.00am, Wednesday 13 September
- **Tokyo** - 2.00am, Wednesday 13 September

[**You can also check your local timezone here**](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Ask%20Different%20Live%20Chat%20Event%20-%20Apple%27s%20%27Let%27s%20meet%20at%20our%20place%27%20event%20%28Fall%202017%29&iso=20170912T10&p1=1239).

So, for some of us (me included) it'll be a very late night or a very early morning!

Hope to see you there!

Comment: Wooooooo! I can't wait to see the theater as well as hear what is about to be released for sale.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty pumped about that theatre and the whole campus. Will definitely have to make a point of visiting it one day. :) As for now, I'm waiting to see what people read into the Apple logo design on the invite! *What* does it mean? Does it mean this? Or maybe that? LOL

Comment: The 10th anniversary iPhone will be called the iPhone X(recently leaked)

Comment: @books453 Actually, a purported photograph of the iPhone X packaging leaked on a Chinese blog about two months ago. I've still got the photo somewhere. But a few weeks back, another purported image of the  iPhone Edition packaging leaked as well. LOL Not long now and we'll find out for certain! :) Hope you can join us for the live chat!